# Apachie redirect based on incoming directory

Tags: apache, redirect

I am running a local website using XAMP not external accessible.

I have been a bit stupid and each time someone has asked for a new copy I have just recreated the DB under another name and created a directory for the site copied the files across and changed which db it is pointing at.

I am now maintaining several site all doing the same thing and each time I find an bug have to copy the files to several places.

The scheme is such that with a small change the pages on the website I could host them all in the same location making the maintenance of the site a lot easier.

The thing is I would like to keep people coming in on different directories and just transform the url in the background so that it points to the single site but with the ?foo="name based on directory".

I hope this is clear.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best place to start is the URL Rewriting Guide on the Apache website.  It is really pretty simple.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

You will also want to determine if you want to redirect to the rewritten URLs, or just rewrite them in the background.  I can't make a recommendation on that without knowing more about how the site is constructed.

Once you have tried it, you will be able to make a much more specific question which will be easier for people to help you with.

Comment: I did look at the Guide a little. I would like it to be rewritten in the back ground.  The structure of the site is that is basically uses one page and is used to monitor servers to see if various applications are running and the version of the software running. the url is structure servername\teamname\*.php  Hope that helps I want to base the redirect on teamname.  thanks

Comment: Have you tried any of the ideas presented in the guide?  Something as simple as RewriteRule teamname([^\.]+).php $1.php?foo=teamname [QSA] might work.